# How do I make a multiple-backgrounds mixin in scss?

Tags: list, sass, background-image

Goal: an scss (I'm using v3.2.1) mixin `preload` used like this (for any number of args > 0):

```
@include preload(url("a.png"), url("b.png"));
```

which outputs the css:

```
.preload { background-image: url("a.png"), url("b.png"); }
```

Including that comma between them. <del>Some failed attempts, which all produce the sought output *minus the comma*:</del> **Edit:** It of course turns out I had faulty calls to the mixin, not bugs in the implementation - all three work just fine:

```
@mixin preload($img_urls...) {
  .preload { background-image: $img_urls; }
}

@mixin preload($img_urls...) {
  .preload { background-image: join($img_urls, (), comma); }
}

@mixin preload($img_urls...) {
  $bgs: nth($img_urls, 1);
  @for $n from 2 through length($img_urls) {
    $bgs: $bgs, nth($img_urls, $n); 
  }
  .preload { background-image: $bgs; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came close with this one here:

```
@mixin preload($img_urls...) {
  .preload { background-image: #{join($img_urls, (), comma)}; } // missing the variable interpolation
}
```

Comment: As it turns out, both are actually correct and working. As long as you don't have bad invocations like `preload($bg $img)` sitting around. :)